# SAPUI5/UI5: Fiori: "Wizard" control step index is not updated correctly

Tags: sapui5

In my Fiori app, I created a sapui5 "wizard" control object having a few steps. I used `.setvisible()` to hide the previous step UIs. BUT, there is a problem -  after moving to the next step, the "step index" (ie the number shown before the step title) always stays as "1". My further study shows that the Wzard control step index is set by a function set in CSS, content: counter(step-counter). It clearly shows that this counter keep having value 1 no matter which step the user moves.

Anyone have an idea to fix this?

Comment: If I understand correctly, step index is the number shown in the circle in the header of the wizard ?
A screenshot would be nice.
It seems to work in [these examples](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.Wizard/samples) .
It would help to analyze the issue if you could post the relevant parts of your coding.
Or even better, if you could build a little example in tools like jsfiddle or plnkr.
This way we could try to debug the issue.
Is there a special reason why you want to hide the previous steps?

Comment: The image with error and code are provided.

Comment: <Wizard id="wizardPort" stepActivate="stepActivate" complete="onWizardCompleted" finishButtonText="Finish" showNextButton="false">
      <steps>
       <WizardStep id="Step1" validated="true" title="Drive" complete="stepCompleted">

Comment: Could you please post your xml view and controller?